# Nativescript load tabs only when displayed

Tags: nativescript

I have setup a custom tab layout defines as following :

> main.xml

```
<StackLayout id="sl_main">
    <t1:explore     id="tab_explore"    visibility="{{ currentActive == 'explore' ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}" />
    <t2:community   id="tab_community"  visibility="{{ currentActive == 'community' ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}"/>
    <t3:profile     id="tab_profile"    visibility="{{ currentActive == 'profile' ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Since all of these tabs are doing cpu intensive operations - such as downloading and uploading images - , **I would like for each tab to be loaded only when it is actually displayed** (which happens when it's `visibility` attribute switches from `collapsed` to `visible`)

**EDIT**
Basically right now when I navigate to `main.js` all the tabs `loaded` events get called.

So when I navigate to `main` I have 3 cpu intensive functions all running one after the other. ( `tab_explore.loaded , tab_community.loaded , tab_profile.loaded` ) What I would like is that if the `visible` tab is `tab_explore` I only call its `loaded` function. Than when `tab_profile` becomes `visible` I `load` that function etc. 
How would you achieve that?

Comment: Could you please explain more clearly?. What do you mean by "I would like for each tab to be loaded only when it is actually displayed"?

Comment: ok i've updated the question! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example the visibility flag is only a visual state (hidden or not). The view is still loaded to memory and is active in the background.

Perhaps your tab-select logic should **add/remove** the partial-views from the container? Instead of just hiding/showing them?

This way the unloaded/loaded events for each view would fire every time you select the proper tab.

Comment: Exactly!How would you load/unload tabs programmatically?